# SSAS Many-to-Many relation without bridge table

Tags: many-to-many, ssas, olap, cube

Is it possible to do a many-to-many relation without a bridge table in SSAS ?
I have one fact table with SubjectId and another fact table with FK_SubjectId and many others keys (related to others dimensions).

In my view datasource the two fact table are connected to each other, but I can't chose the many-to-many relationship in the dimension tab ?

I'm I missing something maybe ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would at least have to define an intermediate dimension. This can be defined based on the first of the fact tables, and can have the `SubjectId` as its only attribute. And this could be invisible to users. But Analysis Services requires an intermediate dimension for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know which dimension to use know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common table.  this mean;  For example you have two fact table create a table which includes only facts primary keys. Like this;

Select id as fact1ID , id as fact2ID from FactTable1 As F1
inner join FactTable2 As F2 ON F1.FK_ID = F2.ID

And create your measures in this hidden table. When you write your measure formula, dont use COUNT ,use DISTINCTCOUNT.  Then create your relations from this common table to your fact tables. Now your fact table will works like dimension table. With this way you can take reports from all other dimension tables between eachother.